# Как получить Request Path в Wireshark

Tags: https, request, wireshark

У меня есть работающий Wireshark на ПК, и есть программа посылающая HTTP/1.1 запросы на сервер. Я вижу домен сайта (`adaf.xyz`), порт на который идут запросы, но не вижу `request path` (например, в url `https://google.com/search` `request path` - `/search`). Хотелось бы узнать как его получить.

Comment: В https вы вряд ли это увидите, он для того и придуман, чтобы увидеть было нельзя

Comment: Если прям очень-очень надо, можно попытаться вытянуть ключ шифрования из программы, но это как минимум нетривиально